# Acronym package and UTF-8

Tags: unicode, acronyms

Are there support of UTF-8? I'm trying to write `\ac{ОС}` (Russian acronym inside) but got strange error

```
Missing \endcsname inserted
```

Here is what in my header:

```
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[footnote,printonlyused,withpage]{acronym}
```

Here is a full example (UTF-8 encoding): http://pastebin.com/TGdwxEBX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you type

```
\acro{ОС}{Операционная Система}
```

`acronym` wants to make an internal control sequence out of the first argument and this fails because, actually, `О` (Cyrillic O) is translated into `\CYRO` which is normally used for printing the glyph, but is illegal in the context of `\csname` (the internal function that allows to build control sequence names).

In the case of `acronym` I'm afraid you have no choice other than adding an ASCII substitute for your acronym:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage[footnote,printonlyused,withpage]{acronym}

\begin{document}

\begin{acronym}
\acro{OS}[ОС]{Операционная Система}
\end{acronym}


\ac{OS} (Очень чистый)

\end{document}
```

[image]

(For producing the picture I shortened the text height.)

Answer (score 0):

(This is an answer to the first version of the question).
The following works:

```
\documentclass{article}

    \usepackage[english,russian]{babel}

    \usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}

    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

    \usepackage[footnote,printonlyused,withpage]{acronym}

\begin{document}
\ac{OC} (Очень чистый) 

\end{document}
```

[image]

So the answer is: yes. However, it is difficult to find the source of your problem without MWE. One of typical reasons is an editor not supporting UTF-8, but I am only guessing.

Comment: Here is my full failing example file: http://pastebin.com/TGdwxEBX

Comment: @DennisYurichev Just edit your answer and add a MWE to the question.

Comment: @DennisYurichev Now I can see: "C" is not Latin "C" but Russian "S".

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke Yep. That was my question about.